# How can I put the data in map function into the styled components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm practicing how to use the map function. 
I made a json file and I want to show each data using map function.

Data is handed over well. But the problem is the way to show images. 
Images are in one file and the way to show images is showing the part of image using `background-position`. 
To do this, I put the taget 'background-position' figures to json file.

*Qusetion* 
But I don't know how to deliever this. Tried to make code, but it doesn't work. 
I think the method of delivering the value to the styled component is wrong. How can I show different images? 
The problematic place is where the id is `list__img`. 
You will understand the code easier if you see codespan.

**code**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import dummy from "./database/DB.json";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(dummy.products);

  return (
    <Wrap>
      <div className="characterList">
        <div className="word">
          <h2 className="word__font">Like Pick!</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="list">
          <ul className="list__ul">
            {data.map((item) => {
              return (
                <div className="list__box">
                  <Card key={item.id} item={item} />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Wrap>
  );
}

// I think I need to deliver the value here
function Card({ item }) {
  return (
    <div className="list__wrap">
      <div className="list__img" />
      {item.nameKr}
    </div>
  );
}

const Wrap = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50vh - 100px);
  width: 1200px;
  display: inline-flex;

  .characterList {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  .word {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
  }

  .word__font {
    font-family: "SFCompactDisplay-Bold", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 38px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .list {
    border: 3px solid grey;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .list__ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
  }

  .list__box {
    margin: 0 9px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  .list__wrap {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .list__img {
    background-image: url(https://www.kakaofriendsgolf.com/img/v3_img_sprites_friends@3x.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /* this part is the problem */
    background-position: 0 {item.position}%;
  }
`;
```

**database**

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "choosik",
      "nameKr": "춘식이",
      "position": 17.647059
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "ryan",
      "nameKr": "라이언",
      "position": 88.235295
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "apeach",
      "nameKr": "어피치",
      "position": 5.882353
    }
  ]
}
```

**codespan**

https://codesandbox.io/s/characterselectmap-t2mqef?file=/src/App.js:0-1990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameter into styled component.

But the way you did it, it wont work.

Separate 'list__img' into new Styled Component, then you can access those props.

Or you can style it inline

```
<div className="list__img" style={{backgroundPosition: `0 ${item.position}%`}} />
```

Comment: Thansk. As you told me I made new styled component and solved the problem